# Which of the Conditional Function is performance effective in HIVE? IF or CASE?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Which of the Conditional Function is performance effective in HIVE? IF or CASE ?

Answer (score 3):

I can speak from experience of working on optimizing complex queries with experts from Hortonworks.   We worked on multi hundred line queries that included multiple  IF/THEN and CASE.  The performance difference is so small as to be unmeasurable.

Worry instead about your joins - i.e. mapside vs side data vs reduce side joins -  and UDF's: those are where the performance improvements are to be found.

We did substantial tuning across a number of areas including a number of different types and skewness of joins, UDF's,  and inline views.  This is not an area that ever surfaced.

Answer (score 0):

Unsubstantiated, but it has been reported that the if/then is actually faster. http://www.oehive.org/node/985